# Problem with Android SDK examples

Tags: android

I'm trying to run the sources from the Android SDK but most of them contains errors and they are not working. I have tried to clean them (eclipse->project->clean) or refresh with F5 but they still contain errors. Do you have any idea what's the matter with these "ready" examples?

Comment: Would help if you could specify what "errors" you get. Also, with "sources", you probably mean the samples?

Comment: ok!i m trying right now to run the BluetoothChat source (android-sdk-windows\samples\android-7\BluetoothChat). i create a new Android Project and then i choose Create Project from existing source!i choose the file and when i m trying to run it it says that contains errors

Comment: How did you create your project in Eclipse ? There's an option to base a new project on a sample. Eclipse usually takes some seconds until the Android SDK is loaded (shows many errors right after starting, then the SDK is loaded and the errors should be gone).

Comment: yes sorry for before i was meaning the samples.the erros are in the src folder.there are errors in both three .java files

Comment: Can you expand on those issues, is it a missing class, syntax error etc. ?

Comment: @dr1ku: i have just done everything it was described in android.development.i create a project from existing source

Comment: e.x.import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;the import android.bluetooth cannot be resolved

Comment: also BluetoothAdapter cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to set the path to the newly downloaded Android SDK, go to Preferences > Android and set the SDK Location. Check out this [helpful guide](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/25/get-started-developing-for-android-with-eclipse/) for more reference

Comment: the apps that i have created e.x. HelloGridView are running with no problem!!the only prob is with this samples of the sdk..

Comment: the API level is automaticaly loaded when i create the project from the existing source

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install API's of the correct version.

Open the SDK manager and install the needed API versions which are missing.

Reopen the development environment, Eclipse, and update Android development if needed.

Then clean the project and if needed rebuild the sample project. The errors should go away.